# Print elements from a list in ascending order(date) whilst splitting the line by each day- C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to print the following in ascending order of the date :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string meter_id = "08002220";
        string calc_constant = "0.1";
        string interval = "00000100";
        List<DateTime> readingDate = new List<DateTime>();
        List<float> volume = new List<float>();
        List<float> odometer = new List<float>();
        var get_timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");

        try
        {
            TextReader textReader = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\umar\Documents\data format\test.csv");
            var csv = new CsvReader(textReader);
            csv.Read();
            csv.ReadHeader();


            while (csv.Read())
            {
                readingDate.Add(DateTime.Parse(csv["Reading Date"]));
                volume.Add(float.Parse(csv["Total Volume"]) / 1000);
                odometer.Add(float.Parse(csv["Odometer"]) / 1000);
            }
            readingDate.Sort();
            var printCMREG = readingDate.Zip(odometer, (first, second) => new { first, second });
            var printCM = readingDate.Zip(volume, (first, second) => new { first, second });


            Console.Write($" MEPMD01, 20080501, EDDYIQ, INSWT:053000,,,{get_timestamp},,OK,W,CMREG,{calc_constant},{interval},");
            foreach (var print in printCMREG)
            {
                if (print.first.Hour == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{print.first.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm")},R0,{print.second},");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n");

            Console.Write($" MEPMD01, 20080501, EDDYIQ, INSWT:053000,,,{get_timestamp},,OK,W,CM,{calc_constant},{interval},");
            foreach (var print in printCM)
            {
                Console.Write($"{print.first.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm")},R0,{print.second},");
            }


        }
        catch(System.IO.IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
   }
```

I have written the above code, which prints the date and time equivalent of a meter reading. What I need at the moment is the ability to sort the dates at the bottom in 24 hour format.

```
        Console.Write($" MEPMD01, 20080501, EDDYIQ, INSWT:053000,,,{get_timestamp},,OK,W,CM,{calc_constant},{interval},");
            foreach (var print in printCM)
            {
                Console.Write($"{print.first.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm")},R0,{print.second},");
            }
```

As can be seen in this line, this prints all the dates together, however, I want to split it up in 24 intervals.

Comment: "I want to split it up in 24 hours by the day." Can you clarify this?

Comment: What does the input in test.csv look like?

Comment: How can I share the test.csv here ?

Comment: @ScottHannen The second part of the code block is representing the part of the code that is supposed to print the 31 days in Januaury. And it does do so, I just want to split the 24 hour days on separate lines. 
one line for 1st of Jan
one line for 2nd of Jan
and so on and so forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this loop:

```
foreach (var print in printCM)
{
    Console.Write($"print.first.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm")},R0,print.second},");
}
```

With this:

```
DateTime currentDay = null;
        foreach (var print in printCM)
        {   
            if(currentDay == null)
            {
                currentDay = print.first.Date;
            }
            else if(currentDay != print.first.Date)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                currentDay = print.first.Date;
            }
            Console.Write($"{print.first.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm")},R0,{print.second},");
        }
```

It will see if the prints are on the same date.  If not it will insert a newline and then update the currentDay variable.

This assumes your sort used earlier in your code is in fact sorting the list.

Comment: That actually, does solve part of the issue, however, I was also looking to append the string  `Console.Write($" MEPMD01, 20080501, EDDYIQ, INSWT:053000,,,{get_timestamp},,OK,W,CM,{calc_constant},{interval},");` to every line.

Comment: If you can point me in that direction, than we are good, and I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you created a class and updated the variables in there, something like this, than you could just run a foreach each loop on the print them out.

```
public class CSVData
{
    public DateTime ReadingDate { get; set; }
    public float Volume { get; set; }
    public float Odometer { get; set; }
}
```